# ¿Cómo implementar un botón de mercado pago en Angular?

Tags: angular, mercadopago

Tengo la siguiente situación. Necesito agregar un botón de mercado pago a un sitio web. Mercado pago tienen la opción de utilizar algo que se llama [Web Tokenize Checkout](https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/developers/es/guides/payments/web-tokenize-checkout/introduction/)

Donde se indica que se tiene que agregar una etiqueta meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Y el botón se carga con un `<form>` que carga un `<script>` externo.

```
<form action="/procesar-pago" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/integrations/v1/web-tokenize-checkout.js"
    data-public-key="ENV_PUBLIC_KEY"
    data-transaction-amount="100.00">
  </script>
</form>
```

El comportamiento esperado es que se visualice un botón, que al darle click cargue un formulario sobre información de tarjeta de crédito. Esto funciona en un archivo html normal, pero Angular "bloquea" las etiquetas `<script>`.

¿Qué opciones tengo para poder utilizar este método de mercado pago? ¿Alguien a implementado un botón de pago a una SPA hecha en Angular?

Comment: pudiste resolver esto?

Comment: No del todo, pude lograr que el script funcionara y se mostrara el formulario pero no pude hacer funcionar todo el proceso.

Comment: Sugiero hacer un componente padre y aquí cargar el script de Mercadopago, luego componentes hijos para cada paso del proceso de pago que quieres crear.

Comment: Puede que esto ayude... https://medium.com/@AncientCitadel/mercadopago-angular-ddfbe875c6a1