# Problema integración checkout mercado pago con angular js

Tags: angularjs, mercadopago

Estoy intentando integrar el checkout de mercado pago de una manera similar a esta...

[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226821/cómo-implementar-un-botón-de-mercado-pago-en-angular?newreg=dcbd8b1ef6aa4b18b277ccaff840e616](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226821/c%C3%B3mo-implementar-un-bot%C3%B3n-de-mercado-pago-en-angular?newreg=dcbd8b1ef6aa4b18b277ccaff840e616)

En la documentación oficial esta esa integración como ejemplo pero no logro que funcione en angular js . Alguien lo pudo resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Para Angular 8, podrias incrustar la libreria mercadopago.js en la etiqueta head al cargar la pagina. En el controlador puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Declara las variables:

```
promise: Promise<any>;
url = 'https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js';
```

Luego el metodo de controlador:

```
loadScripts() {
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = this.url;
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = true;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    return true;
}
```

Por ultimo en el ngOnInit:

```
this.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(this.loadScripts());
  }).then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // configuraciones aquí
      console.log('Loaded scripts.');
  }, 2000);
});
```

Lo ideal seria una suscripcion para la carga del js pero no logré hacerlo, por eso el settimeout.

Saludos.

Comment: Si vi algunas soluciones para versiones de angular superiores, pero tengo el proyecto en JS y seria muy costoso migrarlo en este momento.